# Fail to load eBPF/XDP code on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, clang, bpf, ebpf

The main issue is that I am not able to load a eBPF code in the network interface (XDP).

I am trying to load at Raspberry Pi 3, with the following configuration:

- Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (Buster)
- Kernel 4.19.50-v7+

I am using ip command as follows:

```
$ sudo ip -force link set dev wlan0 xdp obj portfilter.o sec filter
```

Prior to this, I performed clang-7 installation through **apt** and **make** command is working correctly (generation the object).

The **Makefile** source code is as follows:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: (GPL-2.0 OR BSD-2-Clause)

LLVM_VERSION ?= -7 #update with correct LLVM / clang version
LLVM := $(shell clang$(LLVM_VERSION) --version)
CLANG_FLAGS ?= -W -Wall \
    -Wno-compare-distinct-pointer-types

SRCS=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS))
Q ?= @

INCLUDE_DIRS ?= -Iheaders/

%.o: %.c
    @echo "\tLLVM CC $@"
    $(Q) clang$(LLVM_VERSION) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -O2 -emit-llvm -c $< $(CLANG_FLAGS) -o $(patsubst %.o,%.llvm,$@)
    $(Q) llc$(LLVM_VERSION) -march=bpf -filetype=obj -o $@ $(patsubst %.o,%.llvm,$@)
    $(Q) rm $(patsubst %.o,%.llvm,$@)

ifeq ($(LLVM),)
all:
    $(warning Install LLVM to compile BPF sources)
else
all: $(OBJS)
endif

clean:
    rm -f *.llvm
    rm -f *.o

.PHONY: all clean
```

And **portfilter.c** source code that is expected to be loaded:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/icmp.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>
#include "bpf_endian.h"
#include "bpf_helpers.h"

/* 0x3FFF mask to check for fragment offset field */
#define IP_FRAGMENTED 65343

/* Port number to be dropped */
#define PORT_DROP 80

static __always_inline int process_packet(struct xdp_md *ctx, __u64 off){

    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    struct iphdr *iph;
    struct tcphdr *tcp;
    __u16 payload_len;
    __u8 protocol;

    iph = data + off;
    if (iph + 1 > data_end)
        return XDP_PASS;
    if (iph->ihl != 5)
        return XDP_PASS;

    protocol = iph->protocol;
    payload_len = bpf_ntohs(iph->tot_len);
    off += sizeof(struct iphdr);

    /* do not support fragmented packets as L4 headers may be missing */
    if (iph->frag_off & IP_FRAGMENTED)
        return XDP_PASS;

    if (protocol == IPPROTO_TCP) {
        tcp = data + off;
        if(tcp + 1 > data_end)
            return XDP_PASS;

        /* Drop if using port PORT_DROP */
        if(tcp->source == bpf_htons(PORT_DROP) || tcp->dest == bpf_htons(PORT_DROP))
            return XDP_DROP;
        else
            return XDP_PASS;

    } else if (protocol == IPPROTO_UDP) {
        return XDP_PASS;
    }

    return XDP_PASS;
}


SEC("filter")
int pfilter(struct xdp_md *ctx){

    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;
    __u32 eth_proto;
    __u32 nh_off;

    nh_off = sizeof(struct ethhdr);
    if (data + nh_off > data_end)
        return XDP_PASS;
    eth_proto = eth->h_proto;

    /* demo program only accepts ipv4 packets */
    if (eth_proto == bpf_htons(ETH_P_IP))
        return process_packet(ctx, nh_off);
    else
        return XDP_PASS;
}
```

Unfortunately, the actual output after **ip** command is as follows:

```
mkdir /sys/fs/bpf failed: Operation not permitted
Continuing without mounted eBPF fs. Too old kernel?

Prog section 'filter' rejected: Function not implemented (38)!
 - Type:         6
 - Instructions: 38 (0 over limit)
 - License:      

Verifier analysis:

Error fetching program/map!
```

But the expected result is the module loaded correctly in network interface.

*This code is working on a laptop with Ubuntu 18 with Kernel 4.15.0-54-generic*

Please, someone knows how to correctly configure the raspberry pi to work with this code ?

Comment: Just in case, did you check that your kernel has BPF support? What does `grep BPF /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/.config` give you?

Comment: (Or probably your .config file is not at the location I provided -- Just follow pchaigno's instructions instead :) )

Comment: Confirmed that a recompilation of kernel is required. The .config missing eBPF configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **kernel likely isn't compiled with BPF support** (my 4.15 Raspbian isn't). You can check that with the following steps:

```
sudo modprobe configs
zgrep -E "(BPF|XDP)" /proc/config.gz
```

Both `CONFIG_BPF` and `CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL` should be enabled. If they aren't, then you need to **recompile your kernel** with these configs enabled.

Comment: No `zgrep` on the Pi?

Comment: There is. I always forget about these commands. Fixed, thanks!

Comment: Confirmed @pchaigno inspection of .config that
 CONFIG_BPF = y
but
 # CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL is not set


Then a kernel recompile was performed:

$ make menuconfig

Configure the following:

 1) Networking support <ENTER>
 2) Networking options <ENTER>
 2.1) XDP sockets
 2.2) BPF based packet filtering framework <Y>
 2.3) enable BPF Just In Time compiler <Y>
 <Save>
 <Load>

Then also configure:

 1) General setup <ENTER>
 1.1) Enable bpf() system call <Y>
 1.2) Permanently enable BPF JIT and remove BPF interpreter (Y)
 <Save>
 <Load>